# manual SQL injection syntax error on MySQL

Tags: sql-injection, mysql

I am doing a SQL injection training with TryHackMe as shown below. https://tryhackme.com/room/ccpentesting task 18

I am trying to do it the manual way. From [the guide online](https://portswigger.net/web-security/sql-injection/examining-the-database) I know that to get the SQL version in MySQL we can use `SELECT @@version`. However when I try it, it says I have syntax error.

[image]

Update: I was able get rid of the syntax error by adding a space at the end --' to -- '

[image]

however I cant see any output

Comment: 1. Are you sure that the target is MySQL? 2. Look very carefully at the message and make sure you read the text slowly. Do you see the quote marks it reports back to you?

Comment: The error message says it is Mysql. `Select *` may return any number of fields whereas `@@version` returns only one. The UNION query requires that all selects return the same number of fields (in compatible formats). You probably need to add more dummy fields until you find the correct number of fields returned by the query.